How to enforce error on impossible switch case?
There is a linter we can enable for equality check. What about switch case ? This does not seem to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78736339/6727914
How to convert the warning into errors ?
Example:
    /// @deprecated
    enum Role {
      guest,
      user,
      admin,
    }
    enum RoleV2 {
      guest,
      user,
      admin,
    }
    void giveAccessToEverything() {
      /// nuclear codes
    }
    void main () {
      final isAdmin = RoleV2.guest; // Database guy Changed to V2 enum during migration 2.0
      switch (isAdmin) {
        case Role.guest: // nobody saw these
          print("guest");
          break;
        case Role.user: // nobody saw these
          print("superAdmin");
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      /// neither guest nor user, hence admin
      giveAccessToEverything();
    }


What do you mean by "convert the warning into errors" ?

If you run dart analyze, the warning says: "The matched value type 'RoleV2' can never be equal to this constant of type 'Role'. Try a constant of the same type as the matched value type. • constant_pattern_never_matches_value_type".  So you'd make the same change as before to analysis_options.yaml but for constant_pattern_never_matches_value_type.

You have to add the following lines to your analysis_options.yaml.
analyzer:
  errors:
    constant_pattern_never_matches_value_type: error

inter:
  rules:
    constant_pattern_never_matches_value_type: true

Now running flutter analyze will now return these errors.
error • The matched value type 'RoleV2' can never be equal to this constant of type 'Role' • lib/a.dart:22:10 • constant_pattern_never_matches_value_type
error • The matched value type 'RoleV2' can never be equal to this constant of type 'Role' • lib/a.dart:25:10 • constant_pattern_never_matches_value_type

